# actual webpage using rdfa or microdata?

Tags: microdata, rdfa

Where is there a webpage that I can load that is using rdfa or microdata? Or, where should I be looking.

I am not asking for a code example. An actual website that is, today, using rdfa or microdata.

For context, I am looking at the google structured data testing tool. I can more or less randomly try things to see what a search result would look like.

When I search in google and find a detailed result, when I look at the actual webpage, I can not find any rdfa or microdata.

Comment: You can view this web shop I created http://elcigg.nu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you consider opengraph as RDFA? Or you mean rdfa except opengraph since OGP is very widely used?

Anyway here are some examples.

- youtube (microdata, ogp): [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90YdQHjjieg)
- books.google.com (microdata, ogp): [example](http://books.google.ru/books?id=MyFAbwAACAAJ)
- bestbuy (microdata, ogp): [example](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Lenovo+-+IdeaPad+11.6"+Convertible+Touch-Screen+Laptop+-+2GB+Memory+-+Silver+Gray/6963531.p?id=1218817518861&skuId=6963531&st=GL_DOTD_Lenovo&cp=1&lp=1)
- expedia (microdata, ogp, rdfa): [example](http://www.expedia.com/Sydney-Hotels-Rydges-Sydney-Airport-Hotel.h5932305.Hotel-Information)
- booking.com (ogp, rdfa): [example](http://www.booking.com/hotel/ru/radisson-slavyanskaya-business-center.en-gb.html)
- curlingcalendar.com (ogp, rdfa): [example](http://www.curlingcalendar.com/tournaments/289)
- yandex.ru (microdata): [example](http://alexandershubin.moikrug.ru), [example](http://market.yandex.ru/product/8454905/reviews)

Comment: Yes, I should have said "except ogp". So, looking at my question again, what I really wanted to know is only implied. So, I think everyone has answered the question that I asked. I'll ask a different question. Thanks those are useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Rich Snippets test site at http://schema.openspring.net/, check out the 5 links on the left block "Schema.org examples", they all produce a rich snippet preview. All these pages are using RDFa with schema.org.

Comment: Thanks. While that is a web page, it is an example. What I really mean is an actual use of rdf/a or microdata serving the purpose that it claims to have. In other words, someone has put rdf/a or microdata on a web page and it has allowed more details search results to appear in a search engine, and I can look at the web page and see the rdf/a or microdata that caused it to be found. uggh.... I always forget that enter submits the response. Searching for best buy, I see detailed search results. What is the rdf/a or microdata that is causing that to be returned by the search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Many news web sites use microdata for articles. They are quite often incomplete or otherwise [broken](https://notsorandommusingsblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/28/html-microdata-on-news-sites-and-how-broken-it-is-on-those-sites/) though. Some of the better examples are [www.telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/12139477/Julian-Assange-says-he-will-hand-himself-in-on-Friday-if-UN-panel-rules-against-him.html), [independent.co.uk](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/julian-assange-wikileaks-founder-will-accept-arrest-if-un-rules-against-him-a6852551.html). They use the [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) vocabulary.